# Forgot your password points to main blog on multisite install

Tags: multisite

I have set up a Wordpress multisite install, with two blogs - let's call them site1.com and site2.com .

When I access http://site2.com/wp-login.php the 'Forgot your password link' points to http://site1.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword, which is quite confusing.

How can I fix the link to point to point to site2.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answer here: [Password Reset for Users on a Multisite Subsite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/172438/password-reset-for-users-on-a-multisite-subsite) . It shows the code that a plugin uses to set the link to the subsite's lost password, rather than the main site (which is what WP does by default).

You could add that code to your Child Theme's function.php (so you don't mess with the theme code, which will overwrite your changes during  theme update).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. I'll also mark this question as a duplicate.